# website not opening on my network but open on other network

Tags: wordpress, networking

[tracing domain image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvAMr.png) [link](https://vacancyindex.com/wp/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fvacancyindex.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1)

This link is opening on my friends internet, it shows a WordPress admin page, but when I open this link, it shows a wix page. I was using wix hosting but I have changed nameservers of new hosting account. 
I have tried all possible solutions like clearing borwser cache, router reboot, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 01/04/2018

You will need first to clear the local DNS cache by using the following commands:

**Windows**: `ipconfig /flushdns`

**MAC**: `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

**Linux**: `sudo service dnsmasq restart`

---

You might need to change the DNS server on your computer. I would recommend using the following DNS server from Google

```
8.8.8.8

8.8.4.4
```

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: Please lunch Terminal in Mac or if you're a windows user run CMD.  Run the command `nslookup vacancyindex.com` and report me with the results.

Comment: Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com ,
Address:  8.8.8.8 ,

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    vacancyindex.com ,
Address:  23.236.62.147

Comment: I have traced the website domain using cmd and found request timeout error. 
The website opens fine on other internet connections. I have traced website domain using my internet connection and mobile internet data package. It works with mobile internet data package but not with my internet connection.
Please help and try to resolve it.
My IP is: 122.8.125.24

Comment: See the tracing result in question (tracing image)

Comment: You might need to add the correct IP to your website in your host file, this is a temporary fix for the problem. Please add the following line to your host file `192.169.80.98 vacancyindex.com`  Here is a link if you don't know how to change your host file [https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)

Comment: You might need to change your DNS servers again just in case before you go ahead and change your host file. DNS server `208.67.220.220` 
 `208.67.222.222`

Comment: Did you try different DNS server?